# CreateUserWizard ignores .MoveTo

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.5, createuserwizard

This is driving me nuts.  I've reviewed and tried answers from these SO threads, to no avail:

[CreateUserWizard step changing issue after account creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424845/createuserwizard-step-changing-issue-after-account-creation)

[Advancing wizard from code-behind in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270485/advancing-wizard-from-code-behind-in-asp-net)

[Prevent Navigation to CreateUserWizardStep in the Postback event of nextbutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763046/prevent-navigation-to-createuserwizardstep-in-the-postback-event-of-nextbutton/2992049#2992049)

I have added a wizardstep before the one that creates the user on the database:

(0) Personal Details

(1) Sign Up for Your New Account

(2) Complete

In step 0, I have a (dreaded) reCaptcha.  Navigation template for step 0:

```
    <StartNavigationTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="StartNextButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="Next"  OnClick="StartNextButton_Click" CausesValidation="true"/>
    </StartNavigationTemplate>
```

Here, I validate the reCaptcha in the codebehind. This handler declaration was created by VS2012.  If the validation fails, should re-load (and navigate to) the step:

```
    protected void StartNextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recaptcha.Validate();
        if (! recaptcha.IsValid)
        {
            RegisterUser.ActiveStepIndex = 0;
            RegisterUser.MoveTo(RegisterUser.ActiveStep);              
        }
    }
```

Ideally ( and what I've done in earlier versions ) is to set e.Cancel = true when validation fails.  Since VS is only passing EventArgs e, Cancel isn't available, thus the twiddling of ActiveStep.

Debugging shows validation is working, but on validation failure - despite setting the ActiveStepIndex to 0 - I'm passed to Step 1.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Of course, once I posted this, I came up with several alternative ways to accomplish this, but they are either a hack, or a change to the workflow I wanted.  There still should be a way to do this.

Comment: I wound up putting the recaptcha at the end of step 1, and all was well.

Answer (score 2):

The wizard will not stop going to the next step here. You need to define the `OnNextButtonClick` and use this event to cancel moving to next Wizard step.

```
<asp:Wizard OnNextButtonClick="RegisterUser_NextButtonClick" ID="RegisterUser" 
     runat="server">

protected void RegisterUser_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
 {
           if(RegisterUser.ActiveStep==0)
               {
                 recaptcha.Validate();
                    if (! recaptcha.IsValid)
                        {
                            e.Cancel = true;
                        }            
                }
      return;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but didn't get anywhere.  Wound up putting the recaptcha at the end of step 1.